# When speaking, how can I say that the time complexity order of an algorithm is O(N log N)?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, big-o

What term can I use to describe something with O(N log N) complexity?

For example:

- O(1): Constant
- O(log N): Logarithmic
- O(N): Linear
- O(N log N): ??????
- O(N<sup>2</sup>): Quadratic
- O(N<sup>3</sup>): Cubic

Comment: I often here the broad term "quasi-linear" to mean `O(n · f(n))` where `f(n) << n`. But this matches also things like `O(n · log log n)` and `O(n α(n))` where `α(n)` is the inverse of the Ackermann function.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities

Comment: "Oh enn log enn" is probably good enough.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate here: [What is the name the class of functions described by O(n log n)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76317/what-is-the-name-the-class-of-functions-described-by-on-log-n)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

"N log N" is as good as you're going to get, and should be well understood by professional programmers. You can't expect there to be a single word to describe every complexity class that exists.

Comment: “can't expect there to be a single word to describe every complexity class” – certainly not. But  (_n_ ⋅ log _n_) is such an important class that it does deserve a name of its own, IMO; and as said by Steve Jessop, _linearithmic_ is pretty common already.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It is indeed common enough that you could argue, that it does deserve a name. But "n log n" is short enough to pronounce (only three syllables) that it works fine as a name. For comparison "Logarithmic" is four syllables. It's more interesting when you get to external algorithms where most of the "n log n" algorithms get complexity $N log_B (N/B)$, that would certainly be a complexity class worthy of a shorter name.

Comment: As a computer science master's degree student, I have heard "enn log enn" throughout my college studies. I have never heard "linearithmic" and would not understand what it meant at first.

Comment: @Kevin: Logarithmic is four syllables, but "log-enn" is only two.  Likewise, O(N^2) is "enn-squared", not "quadratic".  I suppose "cubic" has fewer phonemes than "enn-cubed", but I think the latter term would still be more common.

Answer (score 52):

There is a jargon term [linearithmic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/linearithmic) meaning exactly this.

I don't believe that it's universally understood by all programmers, so if you're not careful then it will obscure more than it informs. Personally I don't normally use it, and if I did then I'd probably define it on first use, for example "this article considers linearithmic (`O(N log N)`) algorithms".

Comment: Never even knew that existed!

Comment: Never heard this name in my life. And I would never guess that linearithmetic is supposed to mean n log n. And my spelling checker thinks it is two words (line arithmetic).

Answer (score 13):

It is sometimes called "loglinear", although that word actually means something different. I would just stick with "N log N", though, as [@Philip's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/290080/1352) suggests.

Comment: What's the alternative meaning for log-linear?  If I wanted a name other than 'N log N', log-linear is the term I'd use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I assume https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis sometimes spelled without the hyphen. Of course with proper namespacing you could happily use the same word for a complexity class.

Comment: @SteveJessop: That's certainly what came up via a Google search.  I'm not sure whether I'm willing to accept the Google/Wikipedia combo as authoritative, though I have zero doubt that log-linear analysis is as described.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: could also mean what I'd call a lin-log or log-lin plot (or, because I'm lazy, actually I'd often call them a log plot as distinct from a log-log one). We might perhaps ask, *which* alternative meaning this answer has in mind :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because the factor `log n` grows slowly, a qualitative description for `O(n log n)` would be "almost linear".  Depending on your audience the class of `O(n log n)` algorithms might be well known, as for example this is the case with fast sorting on `n` items by comparisons.

Comment: It's really "slightly more than linear". n / log log n would be "almost linear".